# C# Result to a new line

Tags: c#

Ive got one text encrypter where I can add the line I want to encrypt to textbox and the output will be in another textbox.
When I try to encrypt it now, i get a result of all of the lines encrypted together. I want to make it one line in input box will be one line in output box. My current code:

```
var simple = new Simple3Des("randompass");
txtEncrypted.Text = simple.Encode(txtInput.Text);
```

**Current result:**

Input:

```
random:random
random:random
random:random
```

Output:

```
0CwlWp0S4hv1oZWeV2uVBEOCOD5sWgpzv1zOM8YAIroTqitkiJr0t9Nnooz8Frs7TgqL7bKnAuBLomJjcRQc4+mW2CR1fzej+sJly+X4Xbd8SsAFG0Rg==
```

**Result I want:**

Input:

```
random:random
random:random
random:random
```

Output:

```
0CwlWp0S4hv1oZWeV2uVBEOCOD5sWgpf9eDLpiP82A=
0CwlWp0S4hv1oZWeV2uVBEOCOD5sWgpf9eDLpiP82A=
0CwlWp0S4hv1oZWeV2uVBEOCOD5sWgpf9eDLpiP82A=
```

***Update:***

**1**.Using this:

```
var simple = new Simple3Des("randompass");
txtEncrypted.Text = simple.Encode(txtInput.Text);
```

*The result I get:*

Input:

```
random:random
random:random
```

Result:

```
fuxvDhEy+pUnPREKodMsErFusuSLRZHxtKSNhp1XYgQMmzXSeMKN0dGLn+EQuuCAaWvC4E6mokw=
```

**2**.Using the code in the answer:

```
var simple = new Simple3Des("randompass");
var input = txtAccount.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var output = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var i in input)
    output.AppendLine(simple.Encode(i));

txtEncrypted.Text = output.ToString();
```

*The result I get*

Input:

```
random:random
random:random
```

Result:

```
fuxvDhEy+pUnPREKodMsErFusuSLRZHxtKSNhp1XYgQMmzXSeMKN0dGLn+EQuuCAaWvC4E6mokw=
```

Its really the same result in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each line of text in the input TextBox can be encrypted separately, you could split on the line feed, encrypt each line one at a time, then display the result:

```
var simple = new Simple3Des("randompass");
var input = txtAccount.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var output = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var i in input)
    output.AppendLine(simple.Encode(i));

txtEncrypted.Text = output.ToString();
```